# synchronizing two point grey USB cameras for Stereo using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, camera1394, synchronization, stereo, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have two Firefly MV USB cameras from PoinGrey which are working with the Camera1394 node, Im able to view the images and create an package containing c++ code which uses the cv_bridge node to integrate the stream from both cameras and perform a simple color inversion process on the frames of the images on OpenCV , thanks to this handy tutorial on the web at siddhantahuja.wordpress.com.

Now I would like to get up and running with synchronizing the two cameras (externally) and hopefully calculate the disparity. Currently I synchronize the cameras by enabling a strobe signal (output) and a trigger (input) on the two cameras by setting registers manually using Coriander . However this seems quite inefficient as I have to do it every time the cameras are turned on and is susceptible to errors on my behalf.

So the questions I ask are:

1. What is the best way for me to get and set registers dynamically on the Firefly MV (IIDC 1.3 Compliant) camera? Should I use libdc1394  if so could someone please give me an example or a quick guide?
2. Once the cameras are synchronized I will need to poll the cameras so that one camera waits for the completion of the other cameras frame capture process. Does ROS provide a solution for this? If not how can I program the cameras to do this?

Apologies if the question is very trivial, but im only just starting with OpenCV and ROS. I would greatly appreciate some help.

UPDATE:
Ok, Since my software skills are not up to scratch yet I have not yet been able to set the camera regiasters through the 1394 library in order to poll the cameras to wait for a each other to complete their . However I am sure its possible but I just dont know how to.

Anyways to synchronise the cameras I made an external hardware trigger using a 555 timer circuuit which was able to synchronize my images to a 0.015s delay, by enabling a trigger at a specified frequency.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60830/synchronizing-two-point-grey-usb-cameras-for-stereo-using-opencv?/) by [Gaviria R](https://answers.ros.org/users/4637/gaviria-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zcream](https://answers.ros.org/users/13866/zcream/) on 2014-03-26**:
What was the max frame rate you got from your PGR camera ? Using the external 555 timer sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. The camera1394 driver just supports the IIDC specification. It does not provide that kind of device-dependent processing. Check with Point Grey. They may provide information on how to write a separate program to enable the hardware synchronization.
2. There is a brief [camera1394 tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/Tutorials/UsingMultipleIEEE1394Cameras#Stereo_Cameras) with examples of how to combine two cameras into a stereo pair.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gaviria R](https://answers.ros.org/users/4637/gaviria-r/) on 2013-04-16**:
I did as in the tutorial and it works, thanks! But my issue is that since the images are synchronised using a Master-Slave set up the Master should wait until the slave completes the capture process triggered by the master until a new capture process can start. Do you know how this can do this?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-17**:
Camera1394 does not support that. Each driver node runs independently. The stereo image pipeline puts the images together using the approximate time synchronization parameter.

**Comment by [Gaviria R](https://answers.ros.org/users/4637/gaviria-r/) on 2013-04-21**:
joq thanks for the reply I appreciate the help. I managed to get a workaround in order to get the images synchronised without having to worry about the Polling issue. I will update my post soon.